# Teen comedy movie from the 80's or 90's with a piano teacher

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

I've been looking for a movie I watched as a kid, probably from the 80's but it could be from early 90's or even before the 80's, like late 70's. It was a movie that, from what I remember, the characters were trying to "get lucky", like American Pie and such.

I don't know the original language of the movie because I watched it dubbed and can't remember any text in the screen, but here is a scene and some details in it I remember VIVIDLY:

In this scene we follow a group of AT LEAST three teen-ish male characters.
They enter a building (could be a house with a second floor), and MALE-ONE  enters a room where he will get a piano class. 
A young female piano teacher enters the room and sits beside him in the little piano bench.
The female teacher plays a sequence, which the male is supposed to follow. But as the female is playing the sequence, MALE-ONE reaches in a sneaky-ish way for her panties. The female teacher likes it and let him continue.

We cut back to the other males, waiting for him outside the room, by the stairs I mentioned earlier. MALE-ONE gets out of the room, stops by the door (he may be holding his jacket over his shoulder) and his male friends ask him something. MALE-ONE then encourages MALE-TWO to enter the room and try the same thing on the teacher.

MALE-TWO then enters the room, sits in the piano bench and waits a moment for the teacher.
When the piano professor enters the scene, it is a different teacher. It's an old woman, dressed in a conservative way and with a conservative air about her.
She plays a piano sequence and, while she does it, MALE-TWO tries to sneak his hand to touch  the professor's panties and,  when he does it, professor gets really angry, hits him and he goes out the door, running, with her chasing him. MALE-TWO is followed by his group.

A few things that could help:
MALE-ONE, from what I remember, has a build like young Luke Wilson.
MALE-TWO, from what I remember, has a build like John Candy, or is at least chubby.

Sorry for the long post and the kinda vague details about the movie and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This must be a raunchy Israeli comedy called [Hot Bubblegum](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082528/combined) from 1981.

> Three high school seniors preparing for final exams in the early 1960s have the normal teenage concerns about girls, sex and relationships.
>
> Momo and Yudale take turns mounting Bentzi's foreign buxom cousin, but Yudale and her get stuck together. **Momo raises the bar even further by proving the rumors of an accepting older buxom piano tutor, Fritzi.** Bentzi looks for love.

It contains the *exact* scene you described, complete with the twist in the end where the chubby guy is fooled and tries it on the wrong, older teacher. It's **NSFW** so there's no way I'm embedding it here [I kinda regret clicking it myself ;)] but you can find the scene [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0XHQA0tyHk).

Comment: That's the one! Looks so different in my mind, but it is the one I'm after. Also, I watched it in an afternoon, it was airing on TV, and there are a few things that seems cut from when I saw it. But it is the right movie. What did you do to find it? I've been looking for it for over ten years and I watched it over twenty years ago! Thank you.

Comment: Glad you found it. :) And I just searched for piano tutor plotlines on IMDb. The poster was a dead giveaway, it does look like some sort of *Porky's* clone.

Comment: It DOES look like Porky's! I even thought it was for a while. Then I watched it and saw it wasn't.